# I Want To Make Audio Stop With A JButton, How Would I Do This?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, inputstream, actionlistener

I want to stop the audio stream using a `JButton`, how could I do this?

Here is my code:

```
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;
import sun.audio.AudioStream;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream; 
import java.io.InputStream;

public class twerk {
Thread thread;
static int loo = 1;
static File fl = new File("MYFILE");
public static void frame(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("COLLIN");
    frame.setSize(1086,800);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("MYPICTURE");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(image);
    frame.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.setIconImage(image.getImage());

    JButton button = new JButton("Stop Sound");
    frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    frame.setVisible(true);
}


    public static void PlayClip(){
        try
        {

            String st =fl.getPath();
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(st);
            AudioStream au = new AudioStream(in);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(au);
            if(loo == 1){
                Thread.sleep(1900);
                PlayClip();
            }

        } catch(Exception e){}
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
      frame();
      PlayClip();
}



   }
```

I Want To Stop The au with an actionlistener like this:

```
static class Action implements ActionListener{
       public void actionPreformed (ActionEvent e){
            AudioPlayer.player.stop();
       }
```

How Would I Do This. Maybe I could do something like

```
if(JButton.clicked){
audiostream.player.stop
}
```

any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: your song and your gui are running in different thread, you have to interrupt the other thread, please follow java code convetions

Comment: Please note that we don't need statements in bold in order to read them!

Comment: i don't understand why u have a variable thread you don't use it.. you are freezing your gui with Thread.sleep, and you making recursive call to the same function..

Comment: Please consider replying to Eugene's answer with a comment, at least letting him know that you've read his answer and appreciate his efforts at trying to help you. If the answer helped you, then up-vote it. If it in fact answered your question, then "accept" it by clicking on the check next to it. If it didn't answer your question, then explain the details in your comment. Your feedback will help him and will help motivate him and others to help you more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implementing ActionListener into your twerk class. then implement actionPerformed method in your class and add the listener to the button. For example

```
public class twerk implements ActionListener{
public void twerk() {
    button.addActionListener(this);
// omitted
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton tmp = (JButton)e.getSource();
    if(tmp == button)
        au.player.stop();
}
```

And also it is a good practice to keep your class names to start with upper case letter like `'Twerk'`

Good luck with your application!